# Why python don`t detected postgres in container?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile, psycopg2

Postgres run in docker-container
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5gwZ.png)

Java success connect to db but python can`t I have problem with connect if i connect from program pgAdmin i have connection success but if connect from psycopg2 i can`t get success connection

**My code**

```
import pika
import psycopg2
import json
import sys
import signal



queues = ["create", "update", "remove", "status"]
con_db = None


def create_tables():
    cursor = con_db.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cook (cook_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL);""")
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipe (recipe_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, descripion TEXT NOT NULL, fk_cook_id INTEGER REFERENCES cook(cook_id) NOT NULL);""")
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(f"ERROR unable to create tables: {e.pgerror}")
    finally:
        cursor.close()


def on_message(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(f"Сообщение - {body}; получено с канала - {method.routing_key}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    con_db = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="db",
        user="admin",
        password="admin1234",
        host="localhost",
        port="6544"
    )

    print("Start app....")

    con_pika = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters("localhost", 5672, "/", pika.PlainCredentials("user", "111")))
    channel = con_pika.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queues[0])
    channel.queue_declare(queues[1])
    channel.queue_declare(queues[2])

    channel.basic_consume(queue=queues[0], on_message_callback=on_message, auto_ack=True)
    channel.basic_consume(queue=queues[1], on_message_callback=on_message, auto_ack=True)
    channel.basic_consume(queue=queues[2], on_message_callback=on_message, auto_ack=True)

    create_tables()


    def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        print("Завершение работы...")
        channel.close()
        con_pika.close()
        sys.exit(0)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    channel.start_consuming()
```

**My Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  java-service:
    build:
      context: ./java-spring-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - my-network
  python-service:
    build:
      context: ./python-translate-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      postgres:
          condition: service_completed_successfully
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
      DB_PORT: 6544
      DB_NAME: db
      DB_USER: admin
      DB_PASSWORD: admin1234

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin1234
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    ports:
      - "6544:5432"
    networks:
      - my-network
    hostname: postgres


  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres/src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/db
      - FLYWAY_USER=admin
      - FLYWAY_PASSWORD=admin1234
    command: [ "migrate" ]
    networks:
      - my-network


  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 111
    restart: no
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - my-network
  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

File "/app/./app.py", line 36, in 
psycopg2.connect('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:6544/db')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 6544 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 6544 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Help me please with instruction how it fix or send link with solution

Answer (score -1):

```
psycopg2.connect('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:6544/db')
```

```
    con_db = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="db",
        user="admin",
        password="admin1234",
        host="localhost",
        port="6544"
    )
```

Your code and your error message are different, what are the actual connect parameters you are trying to use? If it does not work after this answer, please provide a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all of the irrelevant docker services removed etc.

In any case, you are trying to connect from the python container to a postgres-db as if that db would be available on the localhost of the container. That's not the case when you run it in a separate container with docker-compose.

You need to

- replace `localhost` in the connection string with the name of the postgres service, so `postgres`
- replace the port with the port inside the container (`5432`), not the exposed one (`6544`)
- Use the admin credentials if you don't have a separate user configured

So this should work if nothing else is configured wrongly:

```
psycopg2.connect('postgres://admin:admin1234@postgres:5432/db')
```